# Optimality gap in CBC solver

Tags: julia, gurobi

Is there a way to set the optimality gap in CBC solver, as of now I am able to set the maximum timings on the solver but can not figure out how to set the optimality gap a the stopping criteria.Thanks a lot.

```
using JuMP , Cbc
m = Model( solver = CbcSolver(Sec=70*60))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
using JuMP, Cbc

model = Model()
set_optimizer(model, Cbc.Optimizer)
set_optimizer_attribute(model, "ratioGap", 0.05)
```

as per the documentation here:

https://github.com/jump-dev/Cbc.jl

ratioGap -- Terminate after optimality gap is smaller than this relative fraction.

Answer (score -1):

`solver.options['ratioGAP']=0.01`

Comment: Could you please explain in detail why this solves the problem instead of just posting it without additional information?